# Three dice are rolled. Find the number of possible outcomes in which at least one dice shows $5$.

Tags: combinatorics

> Three dice are rolled. Find the number of possible outcomes in which at least one dice shows $5$.

I would like to know the error in **my** attempt,  I am aware of the other method which is $6^3-5^3$.

Attempt:

Let the first die show 5. The possibilities for the other two dice are $6\times 6 =36$.

Same can be done with the other two dice.

As a result, answer should be $36 \times 3 - 2 = 108 - 2 = 106$, ($-2$ because of the repetition of 5,5,5 case $3$ times.  )

Comment: You have counted 5, 5, 5 three times, but you should count it *once*. So you should subtract 2. But you have also counted 5, 5, 1 twice...

Comment: You did not take care of repetitions like $(5,5,6)$ or $(5,4,5)$. Btw, it can be solved without using PIE. Find the number of possible outcomes in which no die shows $5$ and subtract.

Comment: @drhab I thought the three dice are different.

Comment: I am not saying that they are not different. But possibilities like $(5,5,6)$ are counted twice in your approach.

Comment: @drhab Is the possibility $(5,5,6) \equiv (6,5,5)$?

Comment: No, it is not. The dice are distingishable.

Comment: What is PIE? ..

Comment: @AvinashN It is the [principle of inclusion/exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Answer (score 2):

Total Number of elements is sample space =$6^3=216$.

Total number of elements in the sample space which contains no $5$ = $5^3=125$.

Thus total number of elements which having at least one $5$ is $=216-125=91$.

**Update after OP request:**

If there is only one $5$.
Total Number of possibilities=$1×5×5×3C1=75$.

If there is only two $5$.
Total Number of possibilities=$1×1×5×3C2=15$.

If there is only three $5$.
Total Number of possibilities=$1×1×1=1$.

Total$=75+15+1=91$

Comment: I am sorry, I have mentioned in the question that I know this method already.

Comment: @Abcd oh yes. Now only I see that. I will edit my answer asap.

Comment: @Abcd You said that was a result of PIE, but here PIE is not applied.

Comment: It doesnt answer the actual question anyway...

Comment: @Abcd I have updated my answer. Kindly see it.

Answer (score 2):

Your method has the looks of a wrong application of PIE.

The correct one is:$$|E_1\cup E_2\cup E_3|=|E_1|+|E_2|+|E_3|-|E_1\cap E_2|-|E_1\cap E_3|-|E_2\cap E_3|+|E_1\cap E_2\cap E_3|=$$$$6^2+6^2+6^2-6-6-6+1=91$$

Here $E_i$ denotes the event that the $i$-th die shows a $5$. This for $i=1,2,3$

Also there is the more simple approach (see my comment on your question) leading to answer $6^3-5^3=91$ and not using PIE.

---

It seems you made it:$$|E_1\cup E_2\cup E_3|=|E_1|+|E_2|+|E_3|-3|E_1\cap E_2\cap E_3|$$which is wrong.

Comment: +1 for good explanation.